# Checking Clojure function equality by name

Tags: clojure, lisp

As an exercise in manipulating code as data I wanted to take a piece of Clojure code and change all the `bar` calls for `foo` calls. But I came across a struggle in checking for function equality. My problem is:

```
(= foo foo) ;returns true
(= foo (first `(foo))) ;returns false
```

What is the proper way of checking for the second equality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you quote the list:

```
> (= 'foo (first '(foo)))
true
> (= 'foo (first (list foo)))
false
> (= foo (first (list foo)))
true
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that symbols in clojure are special: they automatically perform variable substitution.

If your original problem had used a keyword or string, it would have worked perfectly:

```
(= "foo" (first ["foo"])))     => true
(= :foo  (first [:foo ])))     => true

(= "foo" (first '("foo") )))   => true
(= :foo  (first '(:foo ) )))   => true
```

Notice that we need to quote the list to turn off it's default meaning of "function call".

Similarly, a symbol has a default interpretation of "variable substitution":

```
(def doh 5)
(= 5 doh)   => true
```

If we want to treat the symbol `doh` as a piece of data, we need to quote it to turn off the default behavior:

```
(= (symbol "doh") 'doh)   => true
```

NOTE: Using a single-quote recursively quotes everything inside the quoted form.  That means we can turn-off the "function-call" behavior of the parentheses and the "variable substitution" behavior of a symbol with just one single-quote character:

```
(=         'foo    (first '(foo)))   => true
(= (symbol "foo")  (first '(foo)))   => true
```

Note that the `symbol` function will convert a regular text string into a symbol.

Finally, note that the single quote character is just a shortcut in [the Clojure Reader](https://clojure.org/reference/reader) for a "function" named `quote`:

```
(= (quote foo)  (first '(foo)))   => true
```

`quote` is actually a ***special form***, not a function. This means it is built into the compiler and does not follow the normal rules for a function. Otherwise, it would have automatically performed variable substitution and the above would have looked like:

```
(= (quote 5) (first '(foo)))   => false
```

Note that `(quote 5)` and `5` are both the same to the compiler. Since the integer `5` is not equal to the first item of a length-1 list containing the symbol `foo`, the expression is false.